# C++ Multiplayer game using ENet/Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, game-physics, multiplayer, enet

I'm new to networking and multiplayer games in general so i tried to get into this field as challange and to discover more about it. So i decided to make my ready game that is built in cocos2dx multiplayer. I created server-side using enet and basicly what im doing is that im sending the velocity and position.
What i noticied that the sync isnt really perfect i searched in google some says that we should do physics logic in server side so my question is:
How can i perfectly sync the movments between the clients ?
If by doing physics stuff in server side how can i do this any  example ?
Im using the (integrated in cocos2dx) Box2D physics engine

Thanks for reading sorry for spelling mistakes

Comment: Please provide a small repeatable and compilable example of your problem. Show what you did so far.

Comment: How big of a problem do you have? Milliseconds? Seconds? Somewhere in between? Are the clients on the same network, different networks, around the world? And remember that unless all clients are on the same network segment the sync between them are always going to be "off" compared to each other, due to latencies in the networks and distances between client and server.

Comment: Some punctuation would be nice too.

Comment: Not really a big thing when a player join the server, the server gonna send to each client that there is one joined and create a player instance using the player class then whenever a player move his person it will send the velocity to other clients and move the instancce have been created akready

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm just testing it using localhost it means latency should be really the difference is really undefinded like sometimes its perfectly sync when the game start but i guess the problem is when the body collides

Comment: Have you ever actually checked whether any of your favourite network games are perfectly synced?

Comment: what do do you mean by "any of your favourite network games"

Comment: If two clients running on the same host as the server gets out of sync, then it's not a network problem. Capture the network traffic (or log it somehow), and see if the clients receive the correct updates from the server, and sends the correct data to the server.

Comment: Yes the problem is not with the network itself as its tested only locally now. I personally thinkt that the problem is with the idea (the way) im doing it (sending only velocity). Im going to log the velcoity and the positions and check it .but do you think running physics on client side is a problem ?

Comment: Only using only velocity is indeed a problem. The server needs to keep track of the positions and while most of the time it's enough to send the vectors (velocity and direction) in updates from the server, it still needs to synchronize all clients with actual positions from time to time.

Comment: Oh and never forget: *Never* trust the client! If you release your game, no matter how little the audience is, you will have cheaters. All state has to be handled by the server.

Comment: but setting positions directly will cause artficial lag

Comment: Not "lag", but it might make some objects jump if it's not done frequently enough. You just have to find the best frequency for the full-poisition updates. Or *always* send the full position (which should not be that much larger than sending a vector).

Comment: and when the position isnt the same i set the position with no interpolation ?

Comment: Since the server always keeps track of all objects and their positions, the position it sends should always be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you play a few instances of a commercial AAA networked game side by side, you'll notice that they're not perfectly synced either.

There's all kinds of lag in networking, and you need to hide that.
Since you can't compensate for the lag (you can't transmit information faster than the speed of light), you need to create a believable simulation of synchronization.
You possibly also don't want to transmit a complete physics update on each frame, but even if you do, packet loss and delays are inescapable facts of networking.

One method that's often used is "dead reckoning", which means that you extrapolate the movement of entities based on their last known trusted position and velocity (and perhaps acceleration).
When you get an update with the actual entity state, you update the state of your entities.
This adds another layer of complexity: you don't want things to teleport, so you also need to interpolate between your extrapolated state and the updated state.

In order to avoid cheaters, you would also make the server be the authority on what the world looks like, and send your input data - key presses, mouse movements, ... - to the server instead of a physics state, and do all calculations on the server as well as on the clients.
(Not just the server because you need to approximate the world while the server is determining "the truth".)

If you now think "but that means that the state of the world is different for different players", you're right.
In reality this doesn't matter - since you very rarely have two players watching the same thing side by side, you only need the world to appear *plausible* to everyone.
What you need to do in practice to make the world plausible depends on your game (a turn-based strategy game isn't as sensitive to time glitches as a fast-paced FPS), as does what shortcuts you can take without destroying the illusion.

Comment: Thanks for all these ideas your answer seems to be logical, but even tho that you are running the two clients and the server on the local machine (localhost) there will be also lag ? I dont think so

Comment: As soon as there's a network involved, there will be lag. If you're using TCP/IP, you may not even send any information until the TCP message buffer is full, and that can be very visible even on the same machine.

Comment: Im using UDP.. i searched a little bit about "dead reckoning" and the other stuff you mentioned you made a good point actually but running the tests on localhost shouldnt show any lag/de-sync innit ?